# Assertion Failed on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: python, opencv

Have been working on basic code to run multiple cameras on raspberry pi 4 and 3

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ret, frame2 = cap2.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('CAM 1',frame)
    cv2.imshow('CAM 2',frame2)
    #cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

 # When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I have been encountering this the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Imageprocessing/webcamtest.py", line 16, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('CAM 1',frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /home/pi/opencv-3.4.3/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:356: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'
```

Tried changing from (-1to 2 ) but no success

One of the cameras turns on but image is displayed. 
The cameras work on web browser.

```
System : Raspberry Pi 4 4GB
OS: Buster 
Python version : 2.7 and 3.7.3
Open CV version 3.4.3
Cameras: Logitech C310 720p
```

Even The Single camera is not working and comes up with the same error

Comment: check `print(frame)` and `print(frame2)` - error can means that you get `None` instead image so it can't check `size.width>0 && size.height>0` when you try to display it

Comment: I did add print(frame) it returned with None. the light on the camera is on but no frames

Comment: did you try `0` in `cv2.VideoCapture(0)` ? Did you activate camera in `Rasbian` system ? Is it working with program `raspstill` and/or python's module `picamera` ?

Comment: yes the camera is activated in the config.

Comment: is camera working with program `raspistill` - ie. `raspistill --output image.jpg` or `raspistill --settings` or for different selections `raspistill --camselect 1 --settings`

Comment: raspistill -o cam.jpg
mmal: Cannot read camera info, keeping the defaults for OV5647
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not detected. Please check carefully the camera module is installed correctly

<br>This is the error when i ran the raspistill

Comment: Now it is not working on the web browser, Apparently it is working with a tensor flow code wit FPS 4~5.

Answer (score 1):

Try to number your cameras starting from 0 (zero):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
```

Comment: Hi,
I have tried that too. including starting from -1